# Create new column based on max value of groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column based on a groupby function, but I'm running into an error. In the sample dataframe below, I want to create a new column where there is a new integer only in rows correspond to the max `seq` variable per user. So, for instance, user122 would only have a number in the 3rd row, where seq is 3 (this users highest seq number).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'user': 
  {0: 'user122',
  1: 'user122',
  2: 'user122',
  3: 'user124',
  4: 'user125',
  5: 'user125',
  6: 'user126',
  7: 'user126',
  8: 'user126'},
  'baseline': 
  {0: 4.0,
  1: 4.0,
  2: 4.0,
  3: 2,
  4: 4,
  5: 4,
  6: 5,
  7: 5,
  8: 5},
 'score': 
 {0: np.nan,
  1: 3,
  2: 2,
  3: 5,
  4: np.nan,
  5: 6,
  6: 3,
  7: 2,
  8: 1},
  'binary': 
  {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 1,
  7: 0,
  8: 1},
  'var1': 
  {0: 3,
  1: 5,
  2: 5,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 3,
  8: 5},
  'seq': 
  {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 2,
  6: 1,
  7: 2,
  8: 3},
})
```

The function I used is below

```
df['newnum'] = np.where(df.groupby('user')['seq'].max(), random.randint(4, 9), 'NA')
```

The shapes between the new column and old column are not the same, so I run into an error. I thought if I specify multiple conditions in `np.where` it would put "NA" in all of the places where it was not the max seq value, but this didn't happen.

```
Length of values (4) does not match length of index (9)
```

Anyone else have a better idea?

And, if possible, I'd ideally like for the newnum variable to be a multiple of the `baseline` (but that was too complicated, so I just created a random digit).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "_multiple of the baseline_"?

Answer (score 0):

the groupby results in fewer rows and not matching 1:1 with your dataframe, hence the error.

Here is how you can accomplish it,

```
#using transform with the groupby to return the max against each of the items
#in the groupby

df['newnum']=np.where ( df.groupby('user')['seq'].transform('max').eq(df['seq']), 
          np.random.randint(4, 9),
         np.nan)
df
```

```
    user    baseline    score   binary  var1    seq     newnum
0   user122     4.0     NaN          1     3      1     NaN
1   user122     4.0     3.0          1     5      2     NaN
2   user122     4.0     2.0          0     5      3     6.0
3   user124     2.0     5.0          0     1      1     6.0
4   user125     4.0     NaN          0     1      1     NaN
5   user125     4.0     6.0          0     1      2     6.0
6   user126     5.0     3.0          1     1      1     NaN
7   user126     5.0     2.0          0     3      2     NaN
8   user126     5.0     1.0          1     5      3     6.0
```

Comment: Thanks! two questions: what does the .eq do you in code? and do you happen to know what I did wrong in mine? thanks!

Comment: @tom, the groupby summarizes rows thereby reducing the row count in the result, hence it  no longer matches the count of rows in the DF. with Transform, we associate the aggregate from the group i.e., max value to all items comprising the groupby. This allows each row to have a max for the group it belongs to. Now,  eq (equal) checks the max value against the seq column, and where it matches it associates the random value. Hope it help clarify and also solved your question

Comment: btw, i was very brief and did indicated in my response the reason why you received the error

Answer (score 0):

```
idxmax = df.groupby('user')['seq'].idxmax()
df.loc[idxmax, 'newnum'] = ...
```

Notes:

- In the first line of the above code, we get indexes of `df` where maximum `seq` is reached for each user.
- In the second line, we're creating a new columns `newnum` and assigning it at the same time to some values at the `idxmax` positions. Other values are `NaN` by default.

#### Update

When we assign a `numpy.ndarray` vector to a new column of a `pandas.DataFrame`, all data frame indexes are used by default to populate the column with values from the vector. If the number of indexes is different from the vector dimension, then you get `ValueError` about size mismatch, as in your case. To avoid it we have to restrict data frame indexes to those which are used in assigning operation. That's the meaning of `df.loc[idxmax, 'newnum']` where we address `df` cells in a new column `'newnum'` with indexes from `idxmax`.

There's a restriction: only the first occurrence of a maximum per user will be used. If there's two or more occurrences of max value for some user, all others will be ignored. You've provided test values with growing `seq` for each user. If this assumption (about growing `seq`) is right, then we can use `idxmax`. Taking the last value in the group will do as well in this case:

```
idxmax = df.groupby('user').tail(1).index
```

If more then one occurrences of max is expected, then we should use some other method, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74033262/14909621):

```
df.groupby('user')['seq'].transform('max').eq(df['seq'])
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand how to apply this, can you elaborate? thanks!